# How to close all the activities of my application?

Tags: android

I've got an application with several activities, for example:

Activity 1 --> Activity 2 --> Activity 3 --> Activity 4

And I would like to close all the activities from any activity and go back at home phone.

Comment: Please check my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9426346/how-to-kill-all-activities-in-android-application/14393598#14393598

Comment: I prefer this solution since it is simpler than the "KillReceiver" solution.

Comment: check my answer [here][1] i hope it to be helpfull


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14001963/finish-all-activities-at-a-time/24833606#24833606

Answer (score 23):

You can achieve that by using `BroadcastReceivers`:

- Create a `BaseActivity` like this:

---

```
public class BaseActivity extends Activity {
    private KillReceiver mKillReceiver;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        mKillReceiver = new KillReceiver();
        registerReceiver(mKillReceiver,
            IntentFilter.create("kill", "spartan!!!"));
    }
    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        unregisterReceiver(mKillReceiver);
    }
    private final class KillReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            finish();
        }
    }
}
```

---

- Make your activities extend that `BaseActivity`.
- Whenever you want to clear the stack:

---

```
Intent intent = new Intent("kill");
intent.setType("spartan!!!");
sendBroadcast(intent);
```

---

Comment: Please do not advise people to use nonsense/illegal MIME types for an `Intent` or `IntentFilter`. Action strings can be made sufficiently unique, and you can use `setPackage()` on more recent versions of Android if you are concerned that the unique action string is insufficient.

Comment: The action can be kill, but the example could be nicer if it used content://sparta as it would not crash :-)

Comment: +1  for you , Thanks Cristian your solution works for me and solved my problem very easily, BTW your should change the text "kill" & "spartan!!" :)

Comment: What if some of my activities extend `Activity` and others `PreferencesActivity`? In this scenario I can't have a single BaseActivity. What is the most practical approach in this case?

Comment: Since the code is too short you might want to create a `BasePreferencesActivity` class. If it were longer, what I would recommend is to [**delegate**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delegation_pattern) the logic to a third class

Comment: Please be careful with Runtime Exception because of Bad MIME type.

Answer (score 4):

You can clear all the previous activities using the following flags :

```
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
```

I hope it will help you !

Answer (score 3):

Open up AndroidManifest.xml and find the activity that you would like to return to and add the following attribute

```
android:launchMode="singleTask"
```

For example, HomeActivity class might have this in android manifest

```
<activity android:name=".HomeActivity"
    android:launchMode="singleTask"/>
```

At any point, you can close all activities on top of this one by using startActivity the standard way, for example

```
startActivity(new Intent(this, HomeActivity.class));
```

If you normally pass extras to the intent, there's no need to do this as it will come back in whatever state it was before, and it's even accompanied by an animation like hitting the back button.

Answer (score 2):

> And I would like to close all the activities from any activity

[That is user-hostile in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2033914/quitting-an-application-is-that-frowned-upon/2034238#2034238). Please do not do that.

> and go back at home phone

I have no idea what this means.

If the user presses HOME, your activities can and should remain in RAM for a bit, in case the user returns to your application.

If by "home phone" you mean that one of your activities is the "home" of the application, and you wish to return to that activity when the user presses some button or options menu item, call startActivity() with an Intent that:

- identifies the activity you want to return to
- has `FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP|FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP` in the flags, to indicate that you want to bring that activity forward and get rid of the other activities that the user had previously launched

Comment: FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP|FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP it is not working in my case. Please help me.

Comment: @BorntoWin: Click the "Ask Question" button in the upper right corner, and explain in your question *precisely* what "is not working in my case" means, both the "is not working" and the "in my case" parts.