# How to close all activities?

Tags: android

I want to know how to close all activities from the stack on button click?

Please help.

Thanks,
Monali

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to close all the activities of my application?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5453206/how-to-close-all-the-activities-of-my-application)

Comment: Check above link and vote to delete the question. It has been asked many a times on StackOverflow.

Answer (score 2):

Its a simple Three Step Process.

1>Set a Public Variable in you App in a Generic.class  Something like

```
public static boolean isExit=false;
```

2> When You want to Quit the app. Set the Value.

```
 Generic.isExit=true;
```

3> Add the Code in Every activity of your app

```
    public void onResume() {
    if (Generic.isExit) 
    {

      finish();
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

first all activity in

```
    Intent artical_cat = new Intent(Artical_list.this,Artical_gallery.class);
       startActivityForResult(artical_cat, 9);


 after put all activity in below code 

@Override

protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK && requestCode == 9) {

            setResult(RESULT_OK);

            finish();
        }
}
```

after in which activity in  close to all open activity in set  in below code :

```
     Intent Logout = new Intent(Artical_list.this, Home.class);
            startActivity(Logout);
                setResult(RESULT_OK);

                finish();
```

Answer (score 0):

You could either use startActivityForResult when starting each activity and then finish each activity in each onActivityResult method.

Or you could make a call to your first Activity with the flag`intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);` and an intent parameter to mark that you want to close the activity e.g. `intent.putExtra("CLOSE_MY_ACTIVITY", true);` (You'll want to check for this in onCreate and then call finish etc).