# Finishing Multiple Activity with Single Statement?

Tags: android, android-activity

In android `finish();` is used to close the Current activity. In my application i've more than 4 Activities. I want to finish them with one single statement. How can i done this here.

I've tried the `System.exit(0);` it's not working for me. Why this not working for me also? Anyone guide me here? Thanks in Advance.

Comment: System.exit(0) should never be used because it destroys the activity lifecycle and shutsdown the application immediately.

Comment: when launching a new `Activity`, use `startActivityForResult`, set the result in `onDestroy` of each `Activity`, such as `setResult(-1)`, then in `onActivityResult`, `if (resultCode==-1) { finish(); }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its better to always go back to homeActivity by using startActivity of your home screen. you can find answers here. [How to close all the activities of my application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5453206/how-to-close-all-the-activities-of-my-application)   and  [Is quitting an application frowned upon?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2033914/quitting-an-application-is-that-frowned-upon/2034238#2034238). its already discussed here

Answer (score 2):

Use following set of instructions.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Home.class);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 1):

I've got the answer. I've give the `moveTaskToBack(true);` to my Button Click event. This works fine. Thanks for you all whose reply me and answer me.

Comment: this is not finishing your, activity what you asked. it is just sending your app in back, when user long press on home button ur app will resume where you left it.

Comment: @AnkitA Yes you're right. It pause the last state. Okay, i'll try another answers

Comment: do one thing, if you do not want to save your activity states, add exclude from recent tag in xml in your activity, second thing make your question more generic so every body can know what you are going to achieve. let me know if i can help,