# Clear activity stack programmatically

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

Clearing an activity stack via `Intent` is well documented with [questions like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12947916/android-remove-all-the-previous-activities-from-the-back-stack).

**However this solution assumes that you are moving from one activity to another. Is there a way to clear this stack programmatically without having to start a new activity using an `Intent`?**

To put this question in context:

My app has a database that synchronizes with a master online database. However the app needs to be available offline, so it has a completely replicated database stored locally in `SQLite`. I have an activity called `FullSyncActivity` which basically has a button called `Start Sync`. When the button is pressed, the sync starts (clears existing data and re-downloads from the server) and once the sync is complete, a new activity starts again.

The problem I have is that the user might navigate to the `FullSyncActivity` without fully understanding it's purpose - hence why I do not want to start the sync process when the activity opens (a `Start Sync` button is required). However, I cannot clear the activity stack when the activity is started (using an intent), because if the user cancels without pressing the `Start Sync` button, then they will have nowhere to return to. Ideally I'd like to clear the activity stack *once the user presses the button*. Is this possible?

Comment: Not sure but check if [this](http://www.hrupin.com/2011/10/how-to-finish-all-activities-in-your-android-application-through-simple-call) helps

Comment: So when user presses StartSync button you want to clear Activity back stack? what happens whens Sync is done? User stays at FullSyncActivity?

Comment: @vipul Obviously a new activity will start when the sync is finished. That's not relevant to my question

Answer (score 0):

I would do this by using a broadcast `Intent`. Have each activity register a receiver for a specific broadcast `Intent`. When the user clicks the `Start Sync` button, it should broadcast this `Intent`. When the receiver gets the `Intent`, it just calls `finish()`. In this way you can ensure that all activities end themselves when you send the broadcast `Intent`.