# Remove activites from the stack

Tags: android, android-activity

I have those activities on the stack A->B->C->D and I want to come back to activity B from activity D removing the activities between B and D (A->B).

I have tried this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, B);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
startActivity(intent);
```

But doing that I also delete the A activity from the stack.

Do you know How could I handle that?

Thank you

Comment: Try This this might help

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12947916/android-remove-all-the-previous-activities-from-the-back-stack

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, B);
startActivity(intent);
finish()
```

on the activities that you want to remove from the stack