# How to clear Activity stack at runtime(not while launching intent)

Tags: android-activity, stack

I want to clear Activity stack at runtime based on some conditions such that

.`if(int a=int b) {
// clear activity stack
}`

Please help

Comment: What do you mean by "clear activity stack" ? activity is a class - it doesn't have a "stack". Further, your code won't compile. try to explain what you want to achieve not how you're trying (or believe you should try) to achieve it.

Comment: I just want that when user presses back button ...then based on some condition it should clear all the activity history in the stack.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android: Remove all the previous activities from the back stack](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12947916/android-remove-all-the-previous-activities-from-the-back-stack)

Comment: like what we do by this code intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);