# Logout navigates to Previous Activity

Tags: android, navigation-drawer, logout

I am using LogOut menuitem in  navigation drawer.The flow of an app is as follows,

1. SplashScreen
2. LogInActivity
3. ShopList Fragment (Inside of Activity3)
4. MainActivity   (Here I am having LogOut menu item in Navigation Drawer).

If I press LogOut,I have written code to navigate LogInActivity.

But it moves to **LogOut-->LogInActivity-->ShopList-->LogInActivity**

LogOut Code is as follows,

```
if(id == R.id.nav_logout) {

            commonUtil.dbUtil.open();
            commonUtil.dbUtil.LogOut();
            Intent moveToMain = new Intent(context, LogInActivity.class);
            moveToMain.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
            moveToMain.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
            moveToMain.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            startActivity(moveToMain);
            MainActivity.this.finish();

        }
```

**Worked fine:   (After changed setFlags to addFlags)**

```
if (id == R.id.nav_logout) {

            commonUtil.dbUtil.open();
            commonUtil.dbUtil.LogOut();
            Intent moveToMain = new Intent(context, LogInActivity.class);
            moveToMain.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
            moveToMain.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
            moveToMain.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            startActivity(moveToMain);
            MainActivity.this.finish();

        }
```

Comment: There is a similar question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12947916/android-remove-all-the-previous-activities-from-the-back-stack) with an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to change `setFlags` to `addFlags`

Answer (score 1):

This will clear all previous activities in the stack

```
Intent moveToMain = new Intent(context, LogInActivity.class);
moveToMain.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
startActivity(moveToMain);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
Intent moveToMain = new Intent(context, LogInActivity.class);
moveToMain .setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK |  Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
startActivity(moveToMain);
```