# Close selected activities from applications

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

```
Hi androidians,
```

I have many modules in my application i can go from one module to other by some link. But before going to other modules i want to close all activities related with previous one you can say i have stack of activities for each module i want to clear it before starting with other modules stack.

```
**Example**
 Module1 contains Activity 1,2,3 Module 2 Contains Activity 4,5,6
```

*I travel from go 1->2->3(of module1)  if i move from 3->4(of module2) i want to finish activity 1,2,3(of module1)*

Comment: Have a look at my answer to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11430993/activities-stack-issue/11435380#11435380

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use a flag to clear all other activities in the stack

or a flag to clear history, which should clear the activities in the history

this can be a flag in your intent, before you start the activity `FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP`

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP

Comment: thanks for reply but my 4 activity is not in stack if it is i can use clear_top flag.