# Activities still in back stack when launching activities with FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP|FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP

Tags: android, android-intent

I'm launching an activity (`ActivityA`) using the technique [described here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5453239/111777) with `FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP|FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP`. This works if all of the activities on the  back stack are still in memory. `ActivityA` is shown and if I tap back, the app exits.

If I use [`SetAlwaysFinish`](https://github.com/bricolsoftconsulting/SetAlwaysFinish) to make paused activities be immediately finished and repeat my test, then when I tap back in `ActivityA`, I'm taken to the previous activity. This shouldn't happen.

Am I testing realistic conditions when I use `SetAlwaysFinish`? If so, how do I configure and launch `ActivityA` so that the back stack is really cleared and my test works under both conditions.

Answer (score 0):

Using "set always finish activities" does not simulate any realistic condition.  It is supposed to be used as a debugging help, but since Android doesn't actually finish activities when it needs to recover resources (it actually kills the host process instead), it is little help in debugging or testing real world conditions.