# Android: Clear Activity Stack

Tags: android, android-activity

I want o clear all Activities after clicking on Logout Button. For this I used the following code. Please tell me correct way to implement it.

```
public class LogoutListner implements OnClickListener {

    private Activity mActivity;

    public LogoutListner(Activity a) {
        this.mActivity = a;
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(mActivity, LoginActivity.class);
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY);
        mActivity.startActivity(intent);
    }
```

Comment: This Question was already answered [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12266572/android-kill-all-activities-on-logout)

Answer (score 3):

```
Intent intent = new Intent(mActivity, LoginActivity.class);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
mActivity.startActivity(intent);
```