# Logout and Close all activities in Android

Tags: android, android-intent

```
Login > HomePage ->Activity1 ->Activity2->Activity3
```

If once I have gone to Activity3 then from there to Home page.
From there i am trying to logout. It is sending me back to the Login page but if I am pressing the back button of my phone it it showing all the previous activities. Please help me on how can we do this.

This is what i have tried

```
logout.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {    
    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        SharedPreferences myPrefs = getSharedPreferences("SelfTrip", MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = myPrefs.edit();
        editor.clear();
        editor.commit();
        Log.d(TAG, "Now log out and start the activity login");
        Intent loginPageIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), LoginPage.class);
        loginPageIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP); 
        loginPageIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        startActivity(loginPageIntent);

    }
});
```

Comment: check my answer [here][1] i hope it to be helpfull


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14001963/finish-all-activities-at-a-time/24833606#24833606

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Login` activity needs to have `android:launchMode="singleTop"` in Manifest file. Here's [the link](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/tasks-and-back-stack.html) for stack and back stack.

You also need to remove `loginPageIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);` as that will create a new task and put Login as root.

Comment: same issue on device back button cliked all previous are shwoing

Comment: Updated the answer. You need to remove `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK` flag

Comment: same no effect on device back button pressed all previous are shwoing

Comment: and if you replace `getApplicationContext()` with `CurrentActivity.class` - where CurrentActivity is your current activity class?

Comment: And one extra thing: all your activities MUST be on the same task. How are you starting `ActivityX`? You shouldn't have `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK` every time you show a new activity as that will create a new task

Comment: Intent newIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
      ActivityNew.class);
    startActivity(newIntent); this how i am staring every activity

Comment: How can you be sure the activities are all in the same task? replace `getApplicationContext()` with current activity instances ... as there are other contexts each time

Comment: same issue no effect i have done the changes as u suggested me

Comment: Are you finishing the current activity once you start a new one?

Answer (score 3):

```
// check sharedPreferences in all activities
// when you press back button then it will close activity
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    int userId = sharedPreferences.getInt(Login.user_id, 0);

    if(userId==0){
        finish();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can simply force the activity to NOT leave a history in your backstack. This can cause trouble, but should work fine as long as your activities are called linear.

Add the line with noHistory to the manifest:

```
<activity
        android:name="com.example.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"           
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"

        android:noHistory="true" >
</activity>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use another way i.e adding activity in an arraylist of type activity and finish the activity you want from any other activity.