# exit android application programmatically

Tags: android, exit

I have two activities, the first is a splash activity.
I would like to know how to exit the application from the second activity to the homepage.
I've used this method it works BUT it takes to the launcher.

```
public void AppExit() 
{

    this.finish();
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
    intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    startActivity(intent);


}
```

Comment: It should take you to the home page, that is what you are telling it to do. What exactly do you mean `display the menu where the application icon is`?

Comment: i'm sorry, actually it takes to the launcher and i want it to exit to the homepage

Comment: possible duplicate of [Close application and launch home screen on Android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2042222/close-application-and-launch-home-screen-on-android)

Comment: Do you want to minimize the app?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Whenever you wish to exit all open activities, you should press a button which loads the first Activity that runs when your application starts then clear all the other activities, then have the last remaining activity finish. to do so apply the following code in ur project

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), FirstActivity.class);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
intent.putExtra("EXIT", true);
startActivity(intent);
```

The above code finishes all the activities except for FirstActivity. Then we need to finish the FirstActivity's Enter the below code in Firstactivity's oncreate

```
if (getIntent().getExtras() != null && getIntent().getExtras().getBoolean("EXIT", false)) {
    finish();
}
```

and you are done....

From [Finish all activities at a time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14001963/finish-all-activities-at-a-time)

Comment: thank you, this is exactly what i wanted. Thanks for the explanations too ^_^

Comment: you can use this.finishAffinity()

Answer (score 13):

when you want to close your application, you can call

> finishAffinity();

or if you want close it in background also you should write,

android:excludeFromRecents="true"

in AndroidManifest :

```
       <activity
        android:name="com.smart.remote.main.SplashActivity"
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" 
        android:excludeFromRecents="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Comment: finishAffinity() is available only for API > 14 (4.0)

Answer (score 2):

This is the cleanest way I have come across:

```
moveTaskToBack(true);
finish();
```

Answer (score 1):

To finish an activity or exit the app, try this..

```
public void exitApp(View v)
{

finish();

}
```

& use this if for whatever you select to exit the app.

`android:onClick="exitApp"`