# How can I close all the activities in Android?

Tags: java, android-intent, android-activity

I have two activities:
First activity: MainActivity.java

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ChildActivity.class);
.
.
.
startActivity(intent);
```

Second activity: ChildActivity.java

```
btnExit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
          public void onClick(View v)
          {
               //I wanna exit completely app in here, but i can't
                System.exit(0);
          }
  });
```

I've tried a lot of way on StackOverFlow but it's not working. How can i solve my problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

start child activity using
`startActivityForResult(Intent intent, int requestCode);`

For closing child activity use `setResult(RESULT_OK); finish();` in your child activity.

And when it is returned, use finish(); for the same requestCode in your parent activity:

```
@Override
onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent){
  if( requestCode == <yourRequestCode> && resultCode == RESULT_OK)
    finish();
}
```

Comment: Thank you, but I've just solved my problem at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14001963/finish-all-activities-at-a-time