# How startActivityForResult 2 Activity from 1 parent Activity and get onActivityResult when only 1 child is finisched

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-activity, android-lifecycle

I have 3 Activities:

- A: Parent Activity
- B: first Child Activity
- C: second Child Activity

In A Activity open B Activity when button is clicked

```
Intent i = new Intent(this,  ActivityB.class);
startActivityForResult(i, 1);
```

In A Activity there is a Runnable object that in some condition open C Activity

```
Intent i = new Intent(this,  Activityc.class);
startActivityForResult(i, 2);
```

All work and on device i see C Activity over B Activity over A Activity but when i close C Activity with `this.finish();` in A Activity `onActivityResult()` event is not fired. It'll be fired only if i close the B Activity too.

How can i know in A Activity when C Activity is closed and let B Activity opened?

Comment: intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP); use on B Activity

Comment: When B is in foreground then A will be in background. Why would you want it to know if C has closed? Also, SO could kill your A while B is in foreground because of reasons (see "Do not keep activities").

Comment: B Activity must stay opened and A activity must do some async task when C is closed.

Comment: You can't guarantee that that is going to work. I suggest you use another approach like a singleton that performs that task for example. Because there are several situations where the system can destroy your Activity A if it's not on foreground.

Comment: @NaveenTamrakar i have added FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP to ActivityB intent but nothing is changed

Comment: @PedroOliveira if i close A Activity how can i retrive result in `onActivityResult()` event ?

Comment: A will always receive the result but only after all activities above it are finished

Comment: @PedroOliveira that is my problem... I need C result while B remains opened

Comment: Then you will need to change your app architecture. You will need a manager (a singleton class) that manages all that results. When C terminates it notifies the singleton to start the task with the results on it. ActivityA when onResuming will call that singleton and updates it's ui with the data from the task (that may or may be not finished already).

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you wish to exit all open activities, you should press a button which loads the first Activity that runs when your application starts then clear all the other activities, then have the last remaining activity finish. to do so apply the following code in ur project

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), FirstActivity.class);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
intent.putExtra("EXIT", true);
startActivity(intent);
```

The above code finishes all the activities except for FirstActivity. Then we need to finish the FirstActivity's Enter the below code in Firstactivity's oncreate

```
if (getIntent().getBooleanExtra("EXIT", false)) {
    finish();
}
```

[Please See this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14001963/finish-all-activities-at-a-time)

Comment: i don't need to close B Activity, but i need to know when C is closed and with which result in A Activity