# How to exit activity in android

Tags: android, mobile

I am new to android development, I want to exit totally from the activity.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.second);
    Button orderButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button3);
    Button exit = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
    exit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            finish();
        }
    });
 }
```

Comment: This should be OK. Whats the issue?

Comment: i want to totally exit from activity,but the above code send to before activity

Comment: Yes, the above code will `finish` the current activity and therefore the previous activity will come to the foreground

Comment: Thats correct behaviour. If you don't want the activity before to stay on the backstack it's a different issue but one that is easy to solve

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14001963/finish-all-activities-at-a-time@sanjay

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.second);
    Button exit = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
    exit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent homeIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
            homeIntent.addCategory( Intent.CATEGORY_HOME );
            homeIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
            startActivity(homeIntent);
        }
    });
}
```

This is the way to exit totally from the activity

Comment: With this the current activity would still be in the backstack.

Comment: This is starting yet another activity. so instead of having 0 activities like he wants, he would now have 2. Thats doubling the problem.

Comment: @sanjay explain the objectives of 'exit'.

Comment: exit to home...i have two buttons one is back and another is exit .

Comment: Back and home buttons are built into Android. You should not add your own, it goes directly against the google design guidelines, which are a really good idea to read for a new developer

Answer (score 1):

To completely exit you just need to call `finish()` which is a method of `context` (`Activity` is a `Context`)

So from inside your listener you could call

```
MyActivity.this.finish();
```

(Where MyActivity is the name of whatever activity you've written that anonymous listener inside)

Answer (score 1):

use 
`finish();`
in previous Activity when you use Intent to move next Activity. 
hope this will help you.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this is what you want but if like you said, you don't wan't it to go to the previous activity, you could make sure that the previous activity would be "closed" when you came to the new one.

Another thing that you could do would be just to create a new intent to send it to the right activity, making sure that when you leave the other activity it gets closed.

If what you want is to finish everything (all of the activities), you could create an intent to go back to the 1st activity of all, put a flag or a boolean on that intent, and on that 1st activity check the value of that boolean (or flag) and if it is on the state that you want ( that means that you want to close all the activities) simply finish() that 1st activity.

Hope this helped you out.