# Quit app with two activities

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I created an app where I put two principal activities.
This is the code I added in the Manifest:

```
<activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        </activity>
    <activity android:name=".Menu">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

To quit, i connected two methods to two buttons, one in the first activity and one in the second.

```
    public void Quit1(View v){
    finish();
    System.exit(0);
}
public void Quit2(View v){
    finish();
    System.exit(0);
}
```

If i click the first button(connected with Quit1), the app closes(that's what I wanted) but when i press the second one(connected with Quit2), I return at the first activity. How can I quit also in the second activity?

Comment: you can start your first activity with clearTop flag

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14002030/5245903

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Donot use `System.exit(0)`

What it does is , it only finishes the current activity, if you have any other activity in the stack, that activity will be started. For example, you have 2 activities **A** and **B**. You move from activity **A** to **B**, and use System.exit(0) there it will finishes the activity **B** and restarts the app with activity **A**. Same in your case.

Simple use.

```
YourActivity.finish();
```

Answer (score -1):

try this to go back to home screen without respective to any background avcitvity

```
  Intent startMain = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
  startMain.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
  startMain.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
  startActivity(startMain);
```

Comment: whats wrong with this snippet