# How to kill app programmatically?

Tags: android, android-intent, activity-finish

I want to to exit app programmatically. How can I do this ?

I research a lot but not found any solution,Any advice or sample code please ?

I have a button in my adapter class.And when I click it, I want to close app. How can I do this ?

**here is my click evet in adapter class**

```
 public class FooterViewHolder extends ViewHolder {
        public FooterViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    ((MyPageActivity)mContex).finishAffinity();

                }
            });
        }
    }
```

Comment: Have you heard of `finish();` method ?

Comment: I tried but nothing happened.

Comment: I didn't understand you well but does this help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14001963/finish-all-activities-at-a-time

Comment: @podgradle **type cast it with activity.**
`((Activity)context).finish();`

Comment: i trend but can't kill app in adapter class :(

Answer (score 9):

For API >= 16, you can call `finishAffinity()`

For API >= 21, you can call `finishAndRemoveTask()`

[Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27765687/8089770)