# how to destroy android application and clear from memory?

Tags: android

I tried System.Exit(0), but is not that i need;

I'm trying to safely destroy android application and clear it from memory,
can i make a button to exit android application and clear all application from memory ?

Comment: This is an anti pattern. Why do you want to do this?

Comment: System .exit(0) is a very bad idea... [refer here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16480930/2345913)

Comment: And where should be the button? At first screen or each screen?

Comment: Official advice: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=631T7B8HOv4

Comment: exit button is in menu

Comment: Please use below link to get answer. It shows you a clean approach

http://stackoverflow.com/a/42228925/1252158

Answer (score 2):

Calling System.exit() is a bad idea. You can simply call finish() on all the activities you need to kill. Here's a good solution to do this:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/5453228/1369222

The basic idea is to add a broadcast receiver to every activity of your app that will finish itself when a particular "kill activities" intent is fired.

Comment: Why is calling System.exit() a bad idea? I'm looking for a quick exit/closing option at app development stage.

Answer (score 2):

calling finish() will only exit the current activity, not the entire application. however, there is a workaround for this:

Every time you start an Activity, start it using startActivityForResult(...). When you want to close the entire app, you can do something like this:

```
setResult(RESULT_CLOSE_ALL);
finish();
```

Then define every activity's onActivityResult(...) callback so when an activity returns with the RESULT_CLOSE_ALL value, it also calls finish():

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    switch(resultCode)
    {
    case RESULT_CLOSE_ALL:
        setResult(RESULT_CLOSE_ALL);
        finish();
    }
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
```

This will cause a cascade effect closing all activities.

Answer (score 1):

Android doesn't have one entry points in app. You should design according guideline. Link: http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/navigation.html

> can i make a button to exit android application and clear all application from memory ?

No.You should remove all activities from stack (e.g. use finish()).

Comment: button is in menu, on click i want to close application

Answer (score 0):

Do not call `System.exit(0)`.

Check the answer by commonsware

[Is quitting an application frowned upon?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2033914/quitting-an-application-is-that-frowned-upon).

You can use action bar. On click of app icon navigate to home screen of your app and click back button in home screen to exit from the app.

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html

Check the below link clearly shows navigation with screen shots.

http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/navigation.html

Answer (score -1):

`System.exit(0)` is not a better approach. Instead, Call `finish()` in all the activities and the `activity` will be removed from stack.

Comment: i dont have only one activity, i have more activities

Comment: That would remove only current activity from stack, not all.. The OP wants to clear all screens from stack, you should have added more...

Comment: Then call `finish()` on all of them.

Comment: @user2515339 this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16480930/2345913) will certainly solve your prob