# Android Activity-Lifecycle: Relation between onPause and onDestroy

Tags: android, lifecycle, activity-lifecycle

what is the inter-relation between onPause and OnDestroy? why is it that when onPause is declared, onDestroy may not be called? and how do you ensure. The reason that this answer is asked because: I am trying to log the user out when the user decides to terminate app, apparently, it is inadvisable to use onDestroy, as it is only called when the device is low on memory and needs some instances.And i am unsure on how this implementation would work in onPause implementation

Comment: You can study this in detail here [Android- Activity](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#ActivityLifecycle).

Comment: what is onDeclared :) ?

Answer (score 2):

You should not use **onPause** to logout, If you login from the Activity A, and if you try to logout in the **onPause** method of Activity A, then **when you go from Activity A to another Activity B**, the user will be logout automatically. Because when you go to Activity B, the **onPause** method of Activity A is called.

Try to understand the lifecycle of the Activty, for experiment, put **Log.d("youActivityName","method name");** in the methods of your Activities, and play with your app/ project, so that you can understand when are the methods being called.

I would suggest, use a **Button** which will close all the activities and logout from the application.

check this link:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/14002030/4082061

[How to close all the activities of my application?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5453206/4082061)

Answer (score 0):

EDIT : use the onDestroy function

```
@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    //Code
}
```

**onPause()**: Called when the system is about to start resuming a previous activity. This is typically used to commit unsaved changes to persistent data, stop animations and other things that may be consuming CPU, etc. Implementations of this method must be very quick because the next activity will not be resumed until this method returns.
Followed by either onResume() if the activity returns back to the front, or onStop() if it becomes invisible to the user.

**onDestroy()**: The final call you receive before your activity is destroyed. This can happen either because the activity is finishing (someone called finish() on it, or because the system is temporarily destroying this instance of the activity to save space. You can distinguish between these two scenarios with the isFinishing() method.

Comment: As stated in the edited question, I am looking at ways that I could allow app to logout users when the users terminate the app. Apparently, it is inadvisable to use onDestroy as it is unpredictable, it is not called on a regular basis

Comment: I have use that onDestroy method to code the logout, however,I have discovered that the behaviour is very erratic, onDestroyed is not called on a regular basis but on certain instances where I assumed that the device is low on memory